# Exclude variants/rotations of lists in solutions SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I want to exclude multiple rotations/mirrors of a list in my solutions of the predicate. I'll give an example of what I understand are rotations/mirrors of a list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5,1]
[3,4,5,1,2]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

I have to find a predicate that delivers unique sequence of numbers from 1 to N, according to some constraints. I already figured out how to compute the right sequence but I can't find out how to exclude all the rotations and mirrors of 1 list. Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit:

Full predicate. clock_round(N,Sum,Yf) finds a sequence of the numbers 1 to N in such a way that no triplet of adjacent numbers has a sum higher than Sum.

```
clock_round(N,Sum,Yf) :-
   generate(1,N,Xs),
   permutation(Xs,Ys),
   nth0(0,Ys,Elem1),
   nth0(1,Ys,Elem2),
   append(Ys,[Elem1,Elem2],Ym),
   safe(Ym,Sum),
   remove_duplicates(Ym,Yf).

remove_duplicates([],[]).
remove_duplicates([H | T], List) :-    
   member(H, T),
   remove_duplicates( T, List).
remove_duplicates([H | T], [H|T1]) :- 
   \+member(H, T),
   remove_duplicates( T, T1).

% generate/3 generates list [1..N]
generate(N,N,[N]).
generate(M,N,[M|List]) :-
  M < N, M1 is M + 1,
  generate(M1,N,List).

% permutation/2
permutation([],[]).
permutation(List,[Elem|Perm]) :-
  select(Elem,List,Rest),
  permutation(Rest,Perm).

safe([],_).
safe(List,Sum) :-
   (  length(List,3),
      nth0(0,List,Elem1),
      nth0(1,List,Elem2),
      nth0(2,List,Elem3),
      Elem1 + Elem2 + Elem3 =< Sum
   ;  [_|RestList] = List,    % first to avoid redundant retries
      nth0(0,List,Elem1),
      nth0(1,List,Elem2),
      nth0(2,List,Elem3),
      Elem1 + Elem2 + Elem3 =< Sum,
      safe(RestList,Sum)
   ).
```

Comment: You rather need to give the entire predicate. Otherwise there is too much guessing.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Answer (score 2):

So what you want is to identify certain symmetries.  At first glance you would have to compare all possible solutions with such. That is, in addition of paying the cost of generating all possible solutions you will then compare them to each other which will cost you a further **square** of the solutions.

On the other hand, think of it: You are searching for certain permutations of the numbers 1..n, and thus you could fix one number to a certain position. Let's fix 1 to the first position, that is not a big harm, as you can generate the remaining n-1 solutions by rotation.

And then mirroring. What happens, if one mirrors (or reverses) a sequence? Another sequence which is a solution is produced. The open question now, how can we exclude  certain solutions and be sure that they will show up upon mirroring? Like: the number after 1 is larger than the number before 1.

At the end, rethink what we did: First all solutions were generated and only thereafter some were removed. What a waste!  Why not avoid to produce useless solutions first?

And even further at the end, all of this can be expressed much more efficiently with `library(clpfd)`.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

clock_round_(N,Sum,Xs) :-
   N #=< Sum, Sum #=< 3*N -2-1,
   length(Xs, N),
   Xs = [D,E|_],
       D = 1, append(_,[L],Xs), E #> L,    % symmetry breaking
   Xs ins 1..N,
   all_different(Xs),
   append(Xs,[D,E],Ys),
   allsums(Ys, Sum).

allsums([], _).
allsums([_], _).
allsums([_,_], _).
allsums([A,B,C|Xs], S) :-
   A+B+C #=< S,
   allsums([B,C|Xs], S).

?- clock_round_(N, Sum, Xs), labeling([], [Sum|Xs]).
   N = 3, Sum = 6, Xs = [1,3,2]
;  N = 4, Sum = 9, Xs = [1,3,4,2]
;  N = 4, Sum = 9, Xs = [1,4,2,3]
;  N = 4, Sum = 9, Xs = [1,4,3,2]
;  N = 5, Sum = 10, Xs = [1,5,2,3,4]
;  ... .
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility do do that :

```
is_rotation(L1, L2) :-
   append(H1, H2, L1),
   append(H2, H1, L2).

is_mirror(L1, L2) :-
    reverse(L1,L2).

my_filter([H|Tail], [H|Out]):-
    exclude(is_rotation(H), Tail, Out_1),
    exclude(is_mirror(H), Out_1, Out).
```

For example

```
?- L = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,1],[3,4,5,1,2],[5,4,3,2,1], [1,3,2,4,5]],my_filter(L, Out).
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 1], [3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2, 4|...]],
Out = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]].
```